# Generic class dynamic method calls to subclasses

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics

I have the main class one Generic class called File, and two classes called Record1 and Record2 that represented two different types of data.

From the Main class i call Process like this:

```
class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
           xFile<Record1> xfile1 = new xFile<Record1>();
           xml.Load(@"..\Data\xml1.xml");
           string rootElementName = "lana";
           xfile1 = xFile<Record1>.Deserialize(xml.InnerXml, rootElementName);
           string a = xfile1.Process();
       }
   }
```

my file class looks like this

```
namespace OOP
{
    [Serializable]
    public class xFile<T>
    {

        private XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNamespaces = null;
        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces Namespaces
        {
            get
            {
                return this.xmlNamespaces;
            }
        }


        public xFile()
        {
            xmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new XmlQualifiedName[] { new XmlQualifiedName(string.Empty, "urn:LANA") });
            Record = new List<T>();
        }

        public xFile (string abc )
        {

        }

        private List<T> record;
        [XmlElement("record")]
        public List<T> Record 
        { 
            get
            {
                return record;
            }
            set
            {
                record = value;
            }
        }


        public string Process()
        {
            //I need to call the Validate method of each record and i'm not sure how to call them polymorphically bassed on the type of a generic class
        }


        public static xFile<T> Deserialize(string xml, string rootElementName)
        {

            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = rootElementName;
            //xRoot.Namespace = rootNamespace;
            xRoot.IsNullable = true;


            xFile<T> result = null;
            XmlSerializer serializerTarget = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xFile<T>), xRoot);

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                result = (xFile<T>)serializerTarget.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

I have 2 classes called Record1 and Record2 they both implement an interface that defines the Validate method to validate the different types of data in each record.

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Record1 : IServiceRecord
    {
        [XmlElement("ppp1")]
        public string PPP1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlElement("ppp2")]
        public string PPP2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Validate()
        {
            return "Test a";
        }
    }
```

how can i call the Validate method of each of the two classes Record1 and record2 from the xFile<> class?

Thank you!
Bilal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that with a plain generic type, you can't do much beyond simple object semantics.  Because the type parameter could be anything at runtime, the compile must assume nothing about it, except that it will be an object.  That's why you can't do much more than check a generic for equality.

The solution is to give the compiler more up-front information about `T`, i.e. to *constrain* the generic type.  You do this as part of your class definition, like so:

```
[Serializable]
public class xFile<T>
    where T : IServiceRecord
{
    ...
}
```

This `where T : IServiceRecord` line means that *only types implementing `IServiceRecord`* can be used as arguments in `xFile`.  That lets the compiler know that any `T` will have `Validate` on it.

Then, in your `Process` method, it's just like anywhere else in C#:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    record.Validate();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I had this in before i figured that i would need to tell the compiler about the Validate method. i get it. now my next challange is just the syntax in the process method. that's really my bigest issue. is it this.Validate()?

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful and you explain clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `xFile<T>` class contains a `List<T> Record` property, so you should be able to call validate on each member of the list:

```
xfile1 = xFile<Record1>.Deserialize(xml.InnerXml, rootElementName);
foreach(var record in xfile1.Record)
   Console.WriteLine(record.Validate());
```

---

In order to add this to your `Process()` method, you'd need to constrain your generics to allow it:

```
public class xFile<T> where T : IServiceRecord
```

You can then call it:

```
    public string Process()
    {
        foreach(T record in this.Record)
        {
            string validation = record.Validate();
            // Do something with validation
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's very important for me to call the Validate function from inside the process method of the File<> class. Can you please provide me with the sample syntax for that. I'm having a dificult time figuring it out myself.

Comment: @BilalHamdan Added that in the answer for you.